# Responsive Navbar Won't Change Position When Resizing

Tags: css, wordpress

Despite the fact my original account mysteriously disappeared, here's my question for the geniuses over  on this site:

For a long time now, I've been 'attempting' to build a response Wordpress theme from scratch so that I can keep all of my ideas on one website. The issue happens to be with the navigation menu. I have a bit of CSS doing the justice on mobile platforms under 600px in width. However, on screens larger than 600px, I have the navbar set so that it's fixed on the webpage and maintains its position when scrolling up and down. When a screen smaller than 600px visits the site, I have it set so that the navbar *should* change from a fixed to relative position. Despite what I'd changed in my stylesheet, I can't seem to make the navbar switch from a fixed to relative state.

Image of the issue:
http://i.gyazo.com/9e8ac2c12d279bba4e5ff98418c9b0ed.png

When normally on the page over 600px:
http://i.gyazo.com/b54486fb441717e79ed9bd3b44ba2710.png

Here's the code. As you can see, when set to resize under 600px, the position should stay relative, but it doesn't:

```css
    .main-navigation {
        position: fixed;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        clear: both;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        background: url('nav-bg.png') repeat center;
        color: #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0px black;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0px black;
     box-shadow: 0 3px 6px 0px black;
        z-index: 999999;
    }



    .main-navigation ul {
     list-style: none;
     margin: 0;
     padding-left: 0;
    }



    .main-navigation li {
        float: left;
    }



    .main-navigation a {
        display: block;
        padding: 2.5em 3.5em;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: 1.4em;
        color: white;
        color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    }



    .main-navigation ul ul {
     position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 99999;
        display: none;
        float: left;
        padding: 0;
        background-image: url('nav-bg2.png');
    }



    .main-navigation ul ul ul {
     left: 100%;
     top: 0;
    }



    .main-navigation ul ul a {
     width: 200px;
    }



    .main-navigation ul ul li {}



    .main-navigation li:hover > a {
        color: #fff;
        color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
        background: #313131;
        opacity: 0.4;
    }



    .main-navigation ul ul :hover > a {}



    .main-navigation ul ul a:hover {
        background: #313131;
        background: hsl(0, 0%, 19%);
    }


    .main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }



    .main-navigation ul ul li:hover > ul {
     display: block;
    }

    .main-navigation .current_page_item > a,
    .main-navigation .current-menu-item > a,
    .main-navigation .current_page_item > a:hover,
    .main-navigation .current-menu-item > a:hover {
       -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 15px #000000;
       -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px #000000;
       box-shadow:         inset 0 0 15px #000000;
       color: #fff;
    }

    .main-navigation .current_page_ancestor {
       -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 15px #000000;
       -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px #000000;
       box-shadow:         inset 0 0 15px #000000;
    }

    .main-navigation ul ul .current_page_parent,
    .main-navigation .current_page_parent .current_page_item > a {
       -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 15px #000000;
       -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px #000000;
       box-shadow:         inset 0 0 15px #000000;
    } 

    /* Menu Resize */

    .menu-toggle {
        display: none;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

        .menu-toggle {
            display: block;
            height: 3.75em;
            padding: 0 1em;
            font-weight: normal;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-size: 1.4rem;
            text-decoration: none;
            line-height: 3.75em;
            color: white;
            background-image: url('nav-bg2.png');
            position: relative;
        }

     .main-navigation.toggled .nav-menu {
            display: block;
            border-top: 1px solid;
            border-top-color: #fff;
            border-top-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .5);

     }



     .main-navigation ul {
      display: none;
            text-align: center;
            padding-left: 0;
            background-image: url('nav-bg2.png');


     }
        
        
     .main-navigation li { 
      float: none; 
     }

     .main-navigation li a { 
      padding: 1.3em 2em; 
     }

     .main-navigation li li a { 
      padding-left: 4em; 
     }

     .main-navigation li li li a { 
      padding-left: 6em; 
     }

     .main-navigation li:hover > a {
      background: #313131;
      background: hsl(0, 0%, 19%);
     }
     
     .main-navigation ul ul,
     .main-navigation ul ul ul {
      position: relative;
      top: inherit;
      left: 0;
      display: block;
      float: none;
      background-image: url('nav-bg2.png');
     }
     
     .main-navigation ul ul a { width: 100%; }

     .main-navigation ul a:hover,
     .main-navigation ul ul a:hover {
      background: #4d4d4d;
      background: hsl(0, 0%, 30%);
     }

     .main-navigation .current_page_ancestor { background: inherit; }

     .main-navigation ul ul .current_page_parent {
      color: inherit;
      background: inherit;
     }

     .main-navigation .current_page_item > a,
     .main-navigation .current_page_item > a:hover,
     .main-navigation .current_page_item li:hover,
     .main-navigation .current_page_parent .current_page_item > a  {
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px #000000;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px #000000;
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px #000000;  
     }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set the position back to relative for `.main-navigation` - you do so for `.menu-toggle` (which I assume is your dropdown button?)

Try adding this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    .main-navigation {
        position: relative;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Quite a facepalm after I had realized what was wrong.  .menu-toggle is the miniature button that displays simple a simple 'Menu' and shows the full menu when clicked.